# How can I properly display a specific fieldset when selecting an option from styled select menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a styled select menu and I want to display a specific fieldset according to the option selected. The problem is that, with styled select menus, it changes the way the menu works

This is the code that i'm working with:

To show the specific data:

HTML:

```
<select id="viewSelector">
   <option value="0">-- Select a View --</option>       
   <option value="view1">view1</option>
   <option value="view2">view2</option>
   <option value="view3">view3</option>
</select>

<div id="view1">
  <!-- content --> 
</div>
<div id="view2a">
  <!-- content --> 
</div>
<div id="view2b">
  <!-- content --> 
</div>
<div id="view3">
  <!-- content --> 
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.viewMap = {
    '0' : $([]),
    'view1' : $('#view1'),
    'view2' : $('#view2a, #view2b'),
    'view3' : $('#view3')
  };

  $('#viewSelector').change(function() {
    // hide all
    $.each($.viewMap, function() { this.hide(); });
    // show current
    $.viewMap[$(this).val()].show();
  });
});
```

To style the select menu:

JQuery:

```
$('select').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this), numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

    $this.addClass('select-hidden'); 
    $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
    $this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');

    var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
    $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

    var $list = $('<ul />', {
        'class': 'select-options'
    }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
        $('<li />', {
            text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
            rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
        }).appendTo($list);
    }

    var $listItems = $list.children('li');

    $styledSelect.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('div.select-styled.active').not(this).each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
        });
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
    });

    $listItems.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
        $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
        $list.hide();
        //console.log($this.val());
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
        $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
        $list.hide();
    });

});
```

And the css:

```
.select-hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.select {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 220px;
  height: 40px;
}

.select-styled {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #c0392b;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
.select-styled:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 10px;
}
.select-styled:hover {
  background-color: #b83729;
}
.select-styled:active, .select-styled.active {
  background-color: #ab3326;
}
.select-styled:active:after, .select-styled.active:after {
  top: 9px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
}

.select-options {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ab3326;
}
.select-options li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px 0;
  text-indent: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid #962d22;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
}
.select-options li:hover {
  color: #c0392b;
  background: #fff;
}
.select-options li[rel="hide"] {
  display: none;
}
```

And i've tried other different codes that I found on internet but the result is the same, when I select an option, it won't display the data

Comment: Any errors? Anything that could be the problem?

Comment: Yeah, selecting an option from the styled menu doesn't work. If I remove the styles and the jQuery for it, it does work